# How to train your hands while working with punching/ boxing bag

Tags: boxing, punching, conditioning

In real life, when you need to fight you have no gloves. How can I train my hands for real life punching in fight. I read articles that claim that when working with punching/ boxing bag you have to use gloves, otherwise you will injure yourself. What is the solution on one hand not to injure yourself and on the other hand to prepare your hands to real life punching with no gloves while using punching/ boxing bag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touching back on [earlier questions about conditioning](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/8065/how-to-condition-knuckles?noredirect=1&lq=1), there really is no need to do extensive hand conditioning in preparation for fighting. The fact of the matter is that you're not likely to ever be in a fight, the fight will likely last less than a minute, and if you do have to fight, you'll have bigger concerns than split knuckles.

That said, the key is to go progressively. Initially, you're going to want to wear padded gloves and striking more slightly while learning proper technique so that you don't injure your fingers and wrists. You then move on to lighter gloves that don't reduce impact forces as much, but reduce scraping and still distribute the force of the punch by a bit. Then, you move on to cloth wraps or gloves, which still help reduce the scraping, but don't do as much to distribute the force. Lastly, you start doing bag work with bare hands. That, by itself, will gradually weather your hands to the point where you are not likely to hurt yourself punching with your bare hands without damaging the skin and nerves permanently.

And even then, if you punch someone, you're probably going to bruise/split your knuckles (if nothing else, they're likely to be moving as you're punching, creating additional friction), but you're much less likely to break anything, and you're more able to throw a few defensive punches, to prove yourself not an easy target, without injuring your hands.

Comment: Punching to the head is dangerous to your hands because the skull is one of the strongest skeletal structures in our body (second only to the hip) and a natural reaction to being punched is moving the head so that the skull is hit. Full stop. This will probably break your hand, conditioning or not.

Comment: That is true. I can revise my answer to indicate simply that you are likely to break the skin even punching "softer" targets because the other guy is moving in ways that bags don't.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipKlöcking and Macaco Branco, can you give a specific advise how to fight and use your hands in a real life situation in order not to injure your hands and legs?

Comment: @ Avi If you enjoy some form of self-defense training (which I hope you do, since self-instruction does not make much sense), one of the first maxims you should learn is to hit hard targets soft and soft targets hard, ie. slaps to the head, punches to the torso, kicks to the thighs. Same goes for blocks/parries. Blocking a shin with your forearm will probably have unwanted consequences, while meeting it with the side of your calf or a soft hand prevents injuries. If your lessons do not include this, they are probably rubbish.